# ORA-00904 : invalid identifier after grouping clause

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, ora-00904

I'm trying to run this select command:

```
select
    r.id,
    r.trip_reason,
    r.status, 
    to_char(trunc(r.trip_date),'DD/MM/YYYY') AS trip_date,
    c.country, count(a.request_id)           AS AZ_Travelers,
    t.travel_by, 
    tt.type,
    r.trip_city,
    r.nr_non_az,
    initcap(e.first_name || ' ' || e.last_name) AS requestor,
    r.requestor_id

 from et_request r, et_country c, et_travel_by t,
      et_trip_type tt, hr_dwh.pm_employees e, et_approval a     

where nvl(r.archived,0)<>1
  and trunc(r.trip_date) >= trunc(sysdate)
  and r.requestor_id = e.empl_id
  and r.id = a.request_id
  and r.trip_country_code = c.id
  and r.travel_by_id = t.id
  and r.trip_type_id = tt.id

group by r.id, r.trip_reason, r.status, trip_date, c.country, AZ_Travelers,
         t.travel_by, tt.type, r.trip_city, r.nr_non_az, requestor, r.requestor_id
order by r.trip_date;
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ORA-00904: "REQUESTOR": invalid identifier
```

I've paid attention to use every table fields in my `group by` clause but I'm getting this error. Any lead about that?

Comment: I would guess that you can't group by computed fields? Perhaps replace that with `e.first_name, e.last_name`?

Comment: Can you please write it as an answer? It was the solution, thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The database doesn't have a column called `requestor` -- at that point, it's just a label you've told it to give to something in the result set -- which it hasn't generated yet and so doesn't know how to handle when it meets that name in the query.

You could group by the components of that computed column, for example replace `requestor` in your `GROUP BY` statement with `e.first_name, e.last_name`.

Comment: Thank you for your help on that !